# SQL Code Guard and nested transactions rollback?

Tags: sql, transactions, codeguard

I have a stored procedure that may be called from a transaction. When there is an exception I want to rollback the transaction (the top-level transaction). I would like to use something like this:

```
...procedure definition...
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

        --work&logic

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH 
        -- An error occurred!
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK
    END CATCH
END
```

The catch with this is, that the SQL Code Guard reports for this the [warning EI020](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SCG/Execution+rules#Executionrules-EI020EI020%E2%80%93ROLLBACKTRANSACTIONwithoutBEGINTRANSACTION) - ROLLBACK TRANSACTION without BEGIN TRANSACTION. Is there a way to write this properly?

Comment: You pass an error flag back to the calling transaction and roll back from there.

Comment: Where have you put BEGIN TRANSACTION command?

Comment: In the caller procedure. It can also be called from the c# code with 'using TransactionScope'.

Comment: So basically, I should not need the try-catch in the procedure that is being called at all, but rather in the caller procedure/query, right?